# layout_weight=".4" looks bigger than layout_weight=".6"

Tags: android, android-layout

This. I can't understand why first layout looks bigger than second layout if the last one has .6 (60%).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".4" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".6">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Its working reverse, .4 is bigger than .6.

Answer (score 1):

@Miguel Barra apply to this

```
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

replace to

```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

or

```
   android:layout_width="0dp"
```

in your both Relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I have not tried with fractional weight values but theoretically they should work. But the problem here i think is that, you need to set the `layout_width` for both the Relativelayouts to be 0dp. Only then weight parameter would take effect. Give it a try. 
From android docs -

> To create a linear layout in which each child uses the same amount of
>   space on the screen, set the android:layout_height of each view to
>   "0dp" (for a vertical layout) or the android:layout_width of each view
>   to "0dp" (for a horizontal layout). Then set the android:layout_weight
>   of each view to "1".

Answer (score 0):

You should have this.

There are two cases if you are using weight

case 1: if you have horizontal parent. you should have layout_width="0dp"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".6" >

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".4">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

case 1: if you have vertical parent. you should have layout_height="0dp"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".6" >

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".4">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `layout_height = "0dp"` in `LinearLayout`(parent view)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
layout_height = "0dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".6" >

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".4">
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

anotherway is add your childview weight sum value(0.6+0.4=1)

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

in `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1" >
```